# What is the most efficient index type for a varchar(25) reference field?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I noticed a `Join` was taking a very long time and after some experimentation found when I replaced the `ref` field in the `Where` clause

`Where T.ref=234881283`

to the `ID` field the

`Where T.ID=25641`

the results were almost instantaneous.

Both fields are `Indexed` both as `BTREE` and `Normal`.

I need to check with my coder if that ref field actually has to be `varchar(25)` vs `Int` since it is always digit based. Assuming for now there is some good resaon, is there a better way to Index that field for better performance?

`

Comment: please post the query that is causing the issues, the table definition for T and the descriptions of any indexes on that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Where T.ref=234881283
```

If `ref` is a `VARCHAR`, then quote the string it is compared to:

```
Where T.ref=234881283
```

The reason:  MySQL looks at that and says:  "Hmmm, he has some strings, and he is looking for that *number*; I'll convert *all* the strings to numbers *every* time he runs that query."

If the values are *always* numbers, then change `ref` to `INT` (or `BIGINT` if they get bigger than 2 billion).

Comment: Did you mean to say if I don't convert to `int` that I should query like so: `Where T.ref='234881283'`

Comment: Awesome simple reply, took the query from 30-60 seconds to milliseconds. Thanks